# Passport LocalStrategy never called on Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I wrote console.log in LocalStrategy callback but it never called. I use Sequelize for ORM (MySQL).

passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const passport = require('passport')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const UrunModel = require('../models/Urun')

console.log('File is Called') // If my require is wrong. But this log worked.    

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'mail',
    passwordField: 'pw1'
},
    (username, password, done) => {
      console.log('Worked!') // Never Called
      UrunModel.findOne({
          where : {
              UrunName : 'testuser',
              UrunDesc : '123456'
          }
      })
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

index.js

```
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})
const passport = require('passport')

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboardSecrIncKey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

require('./config/passport') //require my passport.js

app.post('/test',(req,res,next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect: '/worked',
    failureRedirect: '/notworked'
  })(req,res,next)
})
```

It redirect me '/notworked' url. I watched 3 or 4 videos but almost same on my code.

Where i am failed ? Please explain my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved:**

LocalStrategy not called when there are empty fields(usernameField & passwordField)

Answer (score 2):

By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.

you use `mail` and `pw1` parameters , check `req.body`, because `req.body` don't have this parameters in the body.

your issue will be solve if you replace

```
{
    usernameField: 'mail',
    passwordField: 'pw1'
}
```

with

```
{
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}
```

Also you can check the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)